# Handle tab order in a widget with many layers of tab widgets

Tags: qt, tabs

I'm trying to build a plugin for QgIS, using QT creator. The plugin is a mixture of different Forms, support for generating plots and reports.

Working with some of the forms, I want to be able to use the tab key in order to navigate in the form. The problem is that I have to layers of tab widgets and it seems like the ui only have one global `tab order` list? I would like to have one separate `tab order` per tab, does it make any sense? Is it possible?

I activated the `tab order` in QT and took a print screen, I know how to change the order but its extremely messy to do that by clicking on everything in the correct order if I have other 100 items..

[image: Tabs in tabs]

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 Options.

The first one is to set all 100+ tabs from the designer GUI. You can switch between tabs while in Tab-Mode by using the overview of all your widgets to the right of the design area. Please note that internally, it is only stored "which widget follows which" in the tab focus. The numbering in the designer is only done to make this "chaining" visible. The big problem with this variant is however that you would have to redo the whole process whenever you add or remove something from your UI.

Thus, you should propably use the second variant and do the tabbing in code after calling setupUi function. This is done via the [`QWidget::setTabOrder`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) function. It tells each widget which one to focus next when it has focus and tab is pressed. A simple example would be:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) : 
    QWidget{parent},
    ui{new Ui::MyClass}
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWidget::setTabOrder(ui->outerTabBar, ui->innerTabBar);
    QWidget::setTabOrder(ui->comboBox1, ui->button1);
    // ....
}
```